# Can Linq `Where` clause query result be different depending on whether query is executed lazily or non-lazily?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Below is a simplified version of my code. I would expect `p1` and `p2` to be equal, and also `p1_after` and `p2_after` to be equal, given that the only difference between `GetPerson1()` and `GetPerson2()` is the `.ToList()` clause forcing query execution, without any change to the selection criteria.

Is my assumption incorrect? I have uncovered a bug in my program which boils down to `p1_after` and `p2_after` being different (`p2_after` is null as expected due to the age having been changed to 26. But `p1_after` still contains the same instance as `p1`).

Is this behavior normal? It seems illogical to me which is why I would like to check. Especially as `p1_after.Age` returns 26 despite `p1_after` having been selected such that its `Age` is 25.

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Person p1 = GetPerson1();
        Person p2 = GetPerson2();

        p1.Age = 26;
        p2.Age = 26;

        Person p1_after = GetPerson1(); // not null, but p1_after.Age is 26
        Person p2_after = GetPerson2(); // null
    }

    public Person GetPerson1()
    {
        return _context
            .Persons
            .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public Person GetPerson2()
    {
        return _context
            .Persons
            .ToList()
            .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Either ef uses some form of memory cache for when using `.ToList()` or it's a bug. I'd recommend going to their github, create an issue and see what the devs have to say about this.

Comment: It all makes sense if you know that EF doesn't overwrite local changes in the change tracker when it re-fetches entities from the database. You'll even see that `p1`, `p2`, and `p1_after` are references to the same object, while `p2_after` is just the result of a query that didn't yield anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess but I have an assumption why your program behaves like that.

After you had changed the age you did not call any of `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync` methods so your changes was not reflected in the database and only locals to your code.

Now when you call `GetPerson1` method again you are asking to get from the database the person which is age is 25 and since the database was not reflected by your changes you are getting the same result as before.
The weird part is why you are getting a different result when you call `GetPerson2` method and here will be my guess - in `GetPerson2` method you perform a `ToList` which brings all the persons into memory and then you filter the results in memory in contrast to `GetPersons1` method when the filtration happens at database level, my guess is that when you call `GetPerson2` method the second time since you are using the same context `EntityFramework` uses some caching mechanism to retrieve all of the persons which makes the list you are filtering on affected by your changes and in this list there is not any person which is age is 25 and that is why p2_after is null.

To confirm or reject my assumption I will try three different scenarios:

- Save the changes to the database between the two calls:

  ```
  public void OnGet()
  {
      Person p1 = GetPerson1();
      Person p2 = GetPerson2();

      p1.Age = 26;
      p2.Age = 26;

      _context.SaveChanges();

      Person p1_after = GetPerson1();
      Person p2_after = GetPerson2();
  }
  ```

  In this case I guess p1_after and p2_after will be the same (both null) because now your changes are also reflected to the database.
- Use a fresh context for each call:

  ```
  public void OnGet()
  {
      Person p1 = GetPerson1();
      Person p2 = GetPerson2();

      p1.Age = 26;
      p2.Age = 26;

      Person p1_after = GetPerson1();
      Person p2_after = GetPerson2();
  }

  public Person GetPerson1()
  {
      using(var context = new ...)
      {
          return context
             .Persons
             .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
             .SingleOrDefault();
      }
  }

  public Person GetPerson2()
  {
      using(var context = new ...)
      {
          return context
             .Persons
             .ToList()
             .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
             .SingleOrDefault();
      }
  }
  ```

  In this case I guess p1_after and p2_after will be the same (both as p1 and p2 were before) because now your changes are not reflected to the database and there is not any caching feasibility since you are using a fresh context every call.
- Use AsNoTracking:

  ```
  public void OnGet()
  {
      Person p1 = GetPerson1();
      Person p2 = GetPerson2();

      p1.Age = 26;
      p2.Age = 26;

      Person p1_after = GetPerson1();
      Person p2_after = GetPerson2();
  }

  public Person GetPerson1()
  {
      return _context
          .Persons
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
          .SingleOrDefault();
  }

  public Person GetPerson2()
  {
      return _context
          .Persons
          .ToList()
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Where(p => p.Age == 25)
          .SingleOrDefault();
  }
  ```

  In this case I guess p1_after and p2_after will be the same (both as p1 and p2 were before) because now EF tracking is disabled - AKA no caching.

Comment: I think you described exactly what is going on. (It was also my assumption when writing this question.) But to me this is wrong/inconsistent, kind of an issue in the framework. The reason I can't call `SaveChanges()` is that further down in the code I can still decide to abort the entire set of changes. In that case, I simply never call `SaveChanges()` and nothing is persisted.